# Using generic constraints in a view

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui

I want to design a view that renders a different input field depending on the type of input. Something like this:

```
struct InputFieldView<Input: InputValue>: View {
    @Binding var input: Input
    
    var body: some View {
        // Different control based on the type of input value
    }
}
```

My initial thought was for this InputValue to be a protocol defining everything that this view needs. Individual implementations of the protocol would expand functionality and enforce restrictions (such as min, max and defaultvalues).

```
protocol InputValue {
    associatedtype Element: Identifiable, Hashable // Not sure yet what Element would need to conform to
    var selectedValue: Element
}

// For use with dropdowns
protocol SelectionElement: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var guid: String { get }
    var description: String { get }
}

protocol SelectionInput: InputValue where Element: SelectionElement {
    var possibleValues: [Element] { get }
}
```

However, probably due to my limited understanding of generics, I can't get this to work for an eventual view:

```
struct InputFieldView<Input: InputValue>: View where Input.Element == Int {
    @Binding var input: Input
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Default", value: $input.value, format: .number)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
    }
}

struct InputFieldView<Input: InputValue>: View where Input.Element == String {
    @Binding var input: Input
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Default", text: $input.value)
    }
}

struct InputFieldView<Input: InputValue>: View where Input.Element: SelectionElement {
    @Binding var input: Input
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("", selection: $input.value) {
            ForEach(input.possibleValues) { value in 
                Text(value.description).tag(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably the wrong way of doing things because swift complains that I'm redeclaring the InputFieldView. But how should I be doing this instead?

---

PS: For context, the input value is part of a Realm Object class that has to eventually be sent back to a server as JSON. The value (FieldValue.value) is, on the serverside, expected to arrive as a String, although I assume I can make this work with a custom Encodable.

```
enum FieldInputType: Int {
    case number = 1
    case float = 2
    case text = 3
    case dropdown = 4
    ... // etc
}

class InputField {
    var guid = UUID().uuidString
    var inputType: FieldInputType
    ...
}

class FieldValue<I: InputValue> {
    var guid = UUID().uuidString
    var value: I
    var inputField: InputField!
    var item: Item
    ...
}
```

My initial solution was to avoid generics altogether and just switch over the InputField's inputType enum:

```
extension FieldValue {
    var intValue: Int {
        get {
            Int(value)!
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self.value = String(newValue)
    }
    var boolValue: Bool {
        get {
            (value == "1")
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self.value = (value ? "1" : "0")
        }
    }
}

struct InputFieldView: View {
    @Binding var fieldValue: FieldValue

    var body: some View {
        switch fieldValue.inputField.inputType {
        case .number:
            TextField("", value: $fieldValue.intValue, format: .number)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        case .text:
            TextField("", text: $fieldValue.stringValue)
        case .toggle:
            Toggle("", isOn: $fieldValue.boolValue)
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you come up with an example using basic SwiftUI wrappers you would have a larger pool of people that can reproduce this code and help you out.

Comment: I initially thought that Realm would inevitably be part of the equation but looking over my posted question I don't necessarily think that's the case. I've rephrased the question and moved the additional context (without realm's property wrappers) to the bottom. Hope this is better!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.